# Finding all LIs that have name="checked"

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to find all LIs with name=checked and hide() them, but this doesn't seem to be working:

```
    $('li').attr("name","checked").hide();

<li name="unchecked" style="display: inline;"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: err the only li you show has the name "unchecked"? am i missing something?

Comment: Curious is the fact that you're using the `name` attribute. Shouldn't it be `class`?

Comment: i would agree with BoltClock here, class is better.

Comment: @Pharabus: Why would using a class be better than an otherwise arbitrary attribute.  Browsers ignore them, and it keeps you from abusing the `class` attribute for things that aren't css related.

Comment: @R0MANARMY I wouldn't say "name" was arbitary also class isn't just for css, the w3c define it as "For general purpose processing by user agents." see http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$('li[name="checked"]').hide();
```

Doing:

```
$('li').attr("name","checked").hide();
```

will change the name of all `lis` to **checked** and then hide them, so it is wrong...

Answer (score 1):

and another one (choose any version of a query)

```
$('li').filter('[name=checked]').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

just to add to the correct answers above, your usage is to set the value of the attribute specified in the first argument to the value specified in the second.